# Why is it only showing the value of variable "voornaam"?

Tags: php, html

First time working with Sessions in PHP. I'm trying to print out a part of the payment info on another page which it redirects you to but it tells me the session variables are undefined when we're on the next page. It doesn't say this for the first session variable AKA voornaam (First name in Dutch)

Page to make the payment with (bestellingmaken.php):

```
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bestellen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="sushipic">
<img src="images/sushipic.jpg">
</div>
<div class="bestellingpagina">
<h1>Maak hier uw bestelling</h1>
//Form to make the order with.
<form action="bestellingoverzicht.php" method="post">
    <p>Voornaam <input type="text" name="voornaam"/></p>
    <p>Achternaam <input type="text" name="achternaam"/></p>
    <p>Email-adres <input type="text" name="emailadres"/></p>
    <p>Straatnaam <input type="text" name="straatnaam"/></p>
    <p>Postcode <input type="text" name="postcode"/></p>
    <p>Woonplaats <input type="text" name="woonplaats"/></p>
    <p>Telefoonnummer <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer"/></p>
    <p>Te bestellen drankjes:</p>
    <p>Cola <input type="checkbox" name="cola"/><select name="colahvl">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select></p>
    <p>Sprite <input type="checkbox" name="sprite"/><select name="spritehvl">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select></p>
    <p>Te bestellen gerechten</p>
    <p>Sushi familiegerecht (Voor 5 mensen)<input type="checkbox" name="gerechten"/></p>
    <p>Teriyaki 5 rolls <input type="checkbox" name="gerechten"/></p>
    //Submit button to submit the order with!
    <p><input type="submit" name="input" value="Doorgaan"/></p>
</form>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['input'])){
//Sets the Session variables for all variables with the input value, so we get to use it on the next page.
//Voornaam
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam;
}
//Achternaam
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$_SESSION["achternaam"] =$achternaam;
}
//EmailAdres
$emailadres = $_POST['emailadres'];
$_SESSION["emailadres"] = $emailadres;
//Straatnaam
$straatnaam = $_POST['straatnaam'];
$_SESSION["straatnaam"] = $straatnaam;
//Postcode
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$_SESSION["postcode"] = $postcode;
//Woonplaats
$woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
$_SESSION["woonplaats"] =$woonplaats;
//Telefoonnummer
$telnmmr = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
$_SESSION["telefoonnummer"] =$telnmmr;
//Cola
$colaselect = $_POST['cola'];
$_SESSION["colaselect"] =$colaselect;
$colaAantal = $_POST['colahvl'];
//Pepsi
$spriteselect = $_POST['sprite'];
$spriteaantal = $_POST['spritehvl'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Page which shows the payment information(bestellingoverzicht.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
echo print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bestellen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="sushipic">
    <img src="images/sushipic.jpg">
</div>
<h1>Uw bestellingsgegevens:</h1>

<p>Naam: <?php echo $_SESSION["voornaam"].$_SESSION["achternaam"]; ?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $_SESSION["emailadres"]; ?></p>
<p>Adres: <?php echo $_SESSION['straatnaam'].$_SESSION["postcode"]; ?></p>
<p>Plaats: <?php echo $_SESSION["woonplaats"]; ?></p>
<p>Telefoonnummer: <?php echo $_SESSION['telefoonnummer']; ?></p>

<?php
if (isset($colaselect))
{
    echo "Er zijn " . $colaAantal . " blikjes Sprite besteld";
}
if (isset($spriteselect))
{
    echo "Er zijn " . $spriteaantal . " blikjes Sprite besteld";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: order info page]

Comment: In your first snippet you have a lot of closing brackets without an opening, is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: What is being closed after `$_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam;`, et al.?

Comment: Why the downvote? The concept of sessions are odd when you just start out using them.

Comment: @Martijn Votes determine the usefulness of a post, not the oddness of the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, you submit the form to bestellingoverzicht.php (you have that as `action` set in your form). So, bestellingmaken.php never gets those values.

To fix this, you can move the code from `bestellingmaken.php` to `bestellingoverzicht.php`.

Further, in the code you currently have in `bestellingmaken.php`, you have `if (isset($_POST){`, which you close after the 'voornaam' part. Then you have more setters (move the achternaam to the session etc), but that syntax is incorrect, that also needs to be placed inside the `if $_POST`.

---

As this is some form of homework, small extra things to learn:

Use proper indentation. Everything inside `{}` had to move 1tab/4spaces to the right. If you have an `if` in an `if`, that needs to be indented 2 tabs.
If you do this in your current code, you will encounter the problem in your code above without our help :)

Also, You don't need to assign the `$_POST` to a variable, and that to a session:

```
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam;

// This is also fine, possible even better:
$_SESSION['voornaam'] = $_POST['voornaam'];
```

That saves a line of code, and you have 8 of those, so you save 8 lines, resulting in smaller, more clear code.

Lastly, you might want to read up a little [into functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm), those will make your code a lot more managed with minimal effort.

Comment: Did this! Works now. I got rid of the isset considering it should only send the form when the submit button is set either way and I got rid of the closing brackets at the start of voornaam.

Answer (score 1):

You close your if condition right after the first assignement :

```
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam;
} // <-- this is your problem
```

Is this exaple your actual code ? It should throw a Parse Error. This should work (comments in caps) :

```
if (isset($_POST['input'])){
//Sets the Session variables for all variables with the input value, so we get to use it on the next page.
//Voornaam
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam;
//} <-- THIS IS A PROBLEM AND SHOULD PARSE ERROR
//Achternaam
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$_SESSION["achternaam"] =$achternaam;
//} <-- THIS TOO
//EmailAdres
$emailadres = $_POST['emailadres'];
$_SESSION["emailadres"] = $emailadres;
//Straatnaam
$straatnaam = $_POST['straatnaam'];
$_SESSION["straatnaam"] = $straatnaam;
//Postcode
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$_SESSION["postcode"] = $postcode;
//Woonplaats
$woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
$_SESSION["woonplaats"] =$woonplaats;
//Telefoonnummer
$telnmmr = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
$_SESSION["telefoonnummer"] =$telnmmr;
//Cola
$colaselect = $_POST['cola'];
$_SESSION["colaselect"] =$colaselect;
$colaAantal = $_POST['colahvl'];
//Pepsi
$spriteselect = $_POST['sprite'];
$spriteaantal = $_POST['spritehvl'];
}
```

Comment: Based on the error messages the user is getting this is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that but yeah I already fixed the closing of the condition, accidentally pasted the previous one. Errors still showing

Comment: @user3783243 according to the question's title, it is ;)

Comment: It would throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`, not `undefined index`

Comment: Maybe because "Sorry about that but yeah I already fixed the closing of the condition, accidentally pasted the previous one"